# Listview not showing first row per each page

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, dataset, datapager

I have a list view with which I am displaying a dataset. There is also a datapager.

The problem is, per each page, the first row of the dataset is not displayed in the list view.

So, the datapager displays text "showing element 1-10 of 22" but on the page, only 9 elements are displayed. The code is too big and complicated to paste here.

My question is, generally :
what can be the problem when the DataSet is right but after the binding, the listview shows 1 row less on each page.

I know my question is not specific enough, but I have to solve this problem and I need general ideas on where to look or how to debug, or what generally causes this kind of "first row not shown" problem.

Thanx

Comment: Have you verified the ListView Height and scrolling enabled ? this might hide the 10th row accidentally.

Comment: That is not the problem. With any number of rows, it omits the first row and displays the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I dont know exactly what the problem was. This is a project developed by a team of programmers, and the bug was caused by something irrelevant to the context that I explained. Thank you all for the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

It's more than likely you're either not showing the first row, or the last row in the set. Check your conditions and comparisons.

Note that a DataSet is 0 based - the first row is `.Rows[0]`, not `.Rows[1]`

Comment: Thanx for the ideas. But there is neither a comparison nor a manual access to the dataset. It is very straightforward, like the following. 'ListView.DataSource = Dataset ; ListView.DataBind();' The dataset is right, but the display is as mentioned, first row missing.

Comment: What happens on the second page - do you get 10 rows?

Comment: Again 9 rows on 2nd page. And only 1 on the third page